# Calling a stored procedure using a SQL data source?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I want to populate a Label using a stored procedure from a SQL data source.
My stored procedure takes two parameters but I dont know how to call it.

My table is similar to this:

```
CityID      CityName             London                               Paris                                   
----------- -------------------- --------------------------------------- --
1           London               0                                       60                                      
2           Paris                50                                      0                                       
3           Berlin               90                                      60                                      
4           Madrid               150                                     90                                      
5           Dublin               30                                      80                                      
6           Rome                 75                                      88
```

My intention is to return a value based on what cities are selected from 2 separate drop down lists.
e.g London, Paris would return 60

It seems that I have the data source set up

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="JourneyPrice" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ 
ConnectionStrings:connectToEnterpriseAssignmentDB %>" SelectCommand="GetBusPrice" 
SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
 <SelectParameters>
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlDepart" Name="city" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
  <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlDestination" Name="column" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

My c# code is :

```
DataView dataViewJourneyPrice = (DataView)JourneyPrice.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
            if (dataViewJourneyPrice != null)
            {


                if (dataViewJourneyPrice.Count > 0)
                    // Whatever column is coming from database
                    lblPrice.Text = dataViewJourneyPrice.ToString();

            }
        }
```

This is not yielding the correct results

Solved:
 `labelBusPrice.Text = dataViewJourneyPrice[0]["ColumnName"].ToString();`

Comment: We need to see some code of some sort here. This is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: are you using Entity Framework? Or ADO?

Comment: By "SQL Data Source" are you specifically referring to `<asp:SqlDataSource />` in ASPX files - or do you mean accessing a SQL Server in general?

Comment: Asp, Ive edited my post to include the relevant code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to pull the value from the data view. Once you correct the column name, you may want to cast it to whatever the true data type is so you can do proper formatting before putting into your label.

```
if (dataViewJourneyPrice.Count > 0)
    // Whatever column is coming from database
    labelBusPrice.Text = dataViewJourneyPrice[0]["ColumnName"].ToString();
```

Comment: The only trouble is the column name can change depending on what the user selects from a drop down list. What would I put in place of ''ColumnName'' ?

Comment: That should work. It is just a string, so it can be whatever you grab as the dropdown list value. As long as the column name matches output of stored proc, you will be fine.

Comment: The output of stored proc never matches the column name. The stored proc returns a value based on selections made in two different drop down lists. I'll edit code to show

Comment: Thanks I solved it , 
    `labelBusPrice.Text = dataViewJourneyPrice[0][0].ToString();`